# Passing Key-Value pair to a COM method from .NET

Tags: c#, com

I have the following problem:
I have a project in C# where I use a third party COM component.

So the problem is that the above component has a method, which takes a string and a number of key-value pairs as arguments. I already managed to call that method through JavaScript like that:

```
 var srcName
 srcName = top.cadView.addSource( 'Database', { driver : 'Oracle', host : '10.10.1.123', port : 1234, database : 'someSID', user : 'someuser', password : 'somepass' } )
 if ( srcName != '' )
 {
  ...
 }
```

... and it worked perfectly well. However I have no idea how to do the same using C#. I tried passing the pairs as Dictionary and Struct/Class but it throws me a "Specified cast is not valid." exception. I also tried using Hashtable like that:

```
Hashtable args = new Hashtable();
args.Add("driver", "Oracle");
args.Add("host", "10.10.1.123");
args.Add("port", 1234);
args.Add("database", "someSID");
args.Add("user", "someUser");
args.Add("password", "samePass");

String srcName = axCVCanvas.addSource("Database", args);
```

and although it doesn't throw an exception it still won't do the job, writing me in a log file

> [   Error] [14:38:33.281]
>   Cad::SourceDB::SourceDB(): missing
>   parameter 'driver'

Comment: Mmmmm accessing a database from javascript...

Comment: Do you have a typelib describing the COM interface?

Answer (score 0):

Could you pass in a list of delimited strings? Something like

List args = new List()

args.Add("key:value);

e.g. args.Add("driver:Oracle);

Comment: I tried that already, does'n work - throws Specified cast is not valid." exception

Answer (score 0):

The ACtiveX component is probably using [`IDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221608.aspx) or [`IDispatchEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sky96ah7(VS.85).aspx) methods to convert the dynamic type into a list of property names, and then accessing them.

Either find a different type to pass (which will also work) via the vendor or documentation, or you are going to need to implement one of those interfaces yourself (`System.Collections.Dictionary` doesn't).

Another thing to try is the scripting [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(VS.85).aspx) type (you will need to import the correct typelib to get to that type).

Comment: Scripting.Dictionary was a very good idea, I never thought of that, unfortunately no success there. I'll try playing with IDispatchEx and let you know if a I think of something. Thanks for the help Anyway.